# Category Not showing in New product upload

Tags: magento-1.9, database, product-attribute

When I try to upload a product in Magento and go to the area where you select which category the product should show up for it shows all categories except the one I just created. I made sure this category had all the same settings at the others.

Comment: clear var/cache, var/session and reindex

Comment: Tried clearing cache and reindexing but its still not showing.